Nested Virtual Environment
Hi I am new to MACOS and I am using conda for installing and running Python scripts. While working like that I decided to create project folders and create venvs inside of the folders. So that whenever I create venv I inherit from conda virtual env. Is it meaningful to do that? Is it the best practice? At the final my terminal indicator shown like that (cantaenv) (base) computername.....
Thank you.

In "inherit from conda" what the word "inherit" means? Python virtual environments don't "inherit" directories.

Actually I don't have installed python outside of the conda env. So that while creating venv in a folder I activate the conda env named(base) after that. With Inheriting I mean calling the python -m venv env_name script inside the conda

"With Inheriting I mean calling the python -m venv env_name script inside the conda" This means for the venv you use python from the conda environment; from the venv point of view the conda environment is the base environment. Perfectly normal, esp. if you don't have any other pythons.

If you have something that you know you need in all the sub-environments, like a command line tool that you use across all the environments, or some package that you know you need for every environment, then it can make sense to do that. I'd use that sparingly though, since the more you have, the more things can run into each other. Like say one of your sub-environments uses the latest version of some package, but another requires an older version for whatever reason, then you'd want to not do a nest there.
The more you do it though, the harder it's going to be to track and manage dependencies. When you update something in the base environment, and then one of your sub-environment projects stops working a few weeks later, you're going to have a harder time remembering exactly what might have broken it, or what version of that package you need for it to work.
